# Align a parbox at the bottom of a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, boxes

Below, how can I align the `\tiny` text in the `\parbox` at the end of the right column table so that its last line is on level with the last row of the left column table?

In general, it would not be a problem if the parbox was moved out of the right table. Edit: I would like to stick with a two-table solution, because otherwise the tex-source will get very confusing. The rows in both tables always have the same baseline, however.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}@{}l@{}@{}l@{}}
Definition of & Definition & Definition and \\
Definition of & Definition & Definition and \\
Dynamic & Validation & Validation of \\
of & Definition & Definition and \\
Definition& Validation & Validation of \\
Definition of & Definition & Definition and \\
of Dynamic & Validation & Validation of \\
Dynamic & Validation & Validation of \\
\end{tabular} 
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{2cm}@{}p{2.5cm}@{}}
market risk & found in funds \\
market options & found in changes of \\
market options & found in funds \\
\\
\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\parbox{4.5cm}{\tiny \spacing{0.8}
To compensate for that, add 5 the following that it cannot 
just use since they do not want the add they the following that 
it cannot find where they went \endspacing}}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is simpler to use a single tabular. And some `\smash` magic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}@{}l@{}@{}l@{ }p{2cm}@{}p{2.5cm}@{}}
Definition of & Definition & Definition and & market risk & found in funds\\
Definition of & Definition & Definition and & market options & found in changes of \\
Dynamic & Validation & Validation of & market options & found in funds \\
of & Definition & Definition and & & \\
Definition& Validation & Validation of & & \\
Definition of & Definition & Definition and & & \\
of Dynamic & Validation & Validation of & & \\
Dynamic & Validation & Validation of &
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\smash{\parbox[b]{4.5cm}{\tiny 
To compensate for that, add 5 the following that it cannot 
just use since they do not want the add they the following that 
it cannot find where they went}}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I just added an intercolumn space between the original left and right tables. Also I removed the `\spacing` and `\endspacing` commands which seem to cause the tiny text to shift a bit towards the bottom.

---

Or, with two tables as in your original code (but I think one should put some struts in the rows to be sure they will have the same height):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}@{}l@{}@{}l@{}}
Definition of & Definition & Definition and \\
Definition of & Definition & Definition and \\
Dynamic & Validation & Validation of \\
of & Definition & Definition and \\
Definition& Validation & Validation of \\
Definition of & Definition & Definition and \\
of Dynamic & Validation & Validation of \\
Dynamic & Validation & Validation of \\
\end{tabular} 
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{2cm}@{}p{2.5cm}@{}}
market risk & found in funds \\
market options & found in changes of \\
market options & found in funds \\
\\
\\ \\ \\ 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\smash{\parbox[b]{4.5cm}{\tiny 
To compensate for that, add 5 the following that it cannot 
just use since they do not want the add they the following that 
it cannot find where they went }}}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will have to be in two tables because otherwise the tex-source will get very confusing (the original tables are longer and have more columns). Sorry for not being clear about this. Nice use of `\smash`, however, it does not seem to be entirely aligned (http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/7647/unledbz.png), or is this the best latex does with different font sizes?

Comment: It seems that the `\spacing` macro is the cause for the slight misalignment at the bottom.

Comment: I have removed from my first answer an enclosing tabular which was left there only by misadvertance. And I then added the way closer to your original. Note that I added some \\ in the right table. Some `\strut`'s should go in the lines, in general, I think, to get the rows to be of the same height.

Comment: Very helpful, greatly appreciated.